# how to turn this python lines code into a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension, spyder

I have been asked to convert these lines into a list comprehension

```
tmaxima = []
ag_maxima = []
for i in sorted_indices:
tmaxima.append(t[i])
ag_maxima.append(a_g[i])
```

Comment: (1) The indentation is syntactically invalid. (2) You will need two list comprehensions. (3) Show your own effort and code to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `sorted_indices` contains only integers:

```
tmaxima = [t[i] for i in sorted_indices]
ag_maxima = [a_g[i] for i in sorted_indices]
```